# Array destructuring into object assignment in a single instruction

Tags: javascript, destructuring

Eslint yells at me about this line because it should be done with array destructuring :

```
postModel.base64File = formFile.split(',')[1];
```

I am concerned because I cannot find a way to do this in a single instruction. The best I came up with is the following :

```
const [, b64] = formFile.split(',');
postModel.base64File = b64;
```

Is there a way to make this assignment in a single instruction ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could destructure to the property directly.

```js
var postModel = {},
    formFile = 'a,b';

[, postModel.base64File] = formFile.split(',');

console.log(postModel);
```

The same with an object and an index as target.

```js
var postModel = {},
    formFile = 'a,b';

({ [1]: postModel.base64File } = formFile.split(','));

console.log(postModel);
```

Comment: Ah, thanks ! I was close with `const [, postModel.base64File] = formFile.split(',');`, which generated about 1 million more errors !